# in unity2d physics, I have noticed that it would cause massive lag if a rigibody collide with lots of colliders at the same time, is there a way to

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

in unity2d physics,  I have noticed that it would cause massive lag if a rigibody collides with lots of colliders at the same time, is there a way to limit the amount of contacts a rigibody could have with a specify layer?